# Create child components with NgFor then call a method of whichever emits an event

Tags: angular, ngfor

I can think of a few ways that I might hack this but I'd like some advice on the most *'Angular'* way of doing it.

I've put together [an example of what I'm doing](http://plnkr.co/edit/NvVmoruZq9j9JqJGsQzy?p=preview).

The main component uses `NgFor` to iterate over a list and create a bunch of child components.
Each child emits an event when clicked which is picked up by the parent. Each child also has a method `update()`.

What I want is the correct way for my main component to get a reference to to whichever child emits an event and call its `update()` method.

Seems pretty simple (probably is pretty simple) but it is quite a central feature of the app I'm building so I want to do it as nice and clean as possible.

Cheers for you help

Comment: I think I don't see what you want to do, why do not directly call the `update()` method when the event is emitted?

Comment: You are right, in my example that would be sensible but my actual app is more complex. I was trying to simplify and maybe took it too far - I need the parent to store a reference to the child that emitted the event. The parent then goes of and does some other stuff and finally calls back to the child based on another trigger. I really just need a way to get a hook into the child that emits the event so I can call back to it later. Sorry, I maybe didn't phrase the question as well as I could have.

Comment: Okay, now I understand, so I think the answer of JB Nizet is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a template variable to reference the child component:

```
<my-child #child *ngFor="let row of rowList;" [id]="row.name"
          (onMD)="processClick($event); child.update()"></my-child>
```

Updated demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zA80iNsLHHULGx9Rbffw?p=preview

Comment: Is there a way to use something like `@ViewChild` to reference the child in the controller as we can do when not using an `*ngFor`?

Comment: This worked a treat. I can pass `child` as a second parameter to `processClick()` and store it in a variable in my parent. I can use this later on to call back to whichever child was clicked. Dead simple once you know how, as I had suspected it would be :). Thanks for the advice

Comment: There is ViewChildren. But that won't help you find which child has just been clicked (other than by looping and find the one which has the id in the event)

Comment: I accepted this answer because it did exactly what I was trying to achieve in a very simple way. I have to say though that the answer given below by @MateuszKocz also makes a lot of sense and seems worth the small amount of refactoring that it will cost to implement. If you are looking for the same solution I was then I'd definitely check them both out before you decide on one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

Since Angular 2 embraced the one-way data flow paradigm, I would argue that the "most 'Angular' way" to solve this problem is to **not** call the `update()` method at all. The state of child components should be provided by the parent.

Whenever the click happens, the new state should be computed in the `App` (parent) component and will be passed down to the `ChildComponent`.

Going this way, you will need to extend the state that is held in the parent, by an additional property (eg. `clicked`):

```
rowList = [{name: "Alice", clicked: false}, ...];
```

(Of course, since `undefined` has the same logical value as `false`, explicit declaration is not really necessary.)

On click, in the handler method, the new state is computed. In this case, it's just a simple boolean value change:

```
processClick(id){
  this.recentClick = id;
  // Create the new array for immutability benefits.
  this.rowList = this.rowList.map(person => {
    if (person.name === id) {
      return {name: person.name, clicked: true};
    } else {
      return person;
    }
  })
}
```

The value is passed down to the child, as any other `@Input`.

```
<my-child *ngFor="let row of rowList;" [id]=row.name [clicked]=row.clicked (onMD)="processClick($event)"></my-child>
```

Now, the child component can change it's behavior depending on the value of the `clicked` property. As a bonus, when using immutable data, you can change the change detection strategy to `onPush` for [some performance benefits](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#reducing-the-number-of-checks).

```
@Component({
    // ...
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() clicked: boolean;

  get prefix() {
    return this.clicked ? "Bye!" : "Hi";
  }
  // ...
}
```

There are multiple benefits of this approach.

- You don't have a hidden state lurking in child components. Parent's "word" is absolute (so called "single source of truth").
- The parent doesn't really need to know or care about what children do with the data or when they need to update.
- You cal easily extract the data somewhere else, and you won't need to write any code making the `update()` behavior works.

The full implementation would look like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/IP8iLKxKGCjHOdgPHJ0h?p=preview

Comment: I accepted the other answer before I saw this and now I am conflicted. The accepted answer worked exactly as I hoped and was the kind of solution I was expecting however I see the sense in you approach and can see how it is a cleaner solution than where I was heading in the long run. I'm probably going to use this I think so thank you for a really good, in depth answer.